# JavaScript simple if statement - print yes

Tags: javascript

```
 if (2<3), console.log (yes)
```

this does not work. How can I fix this? i want to print "yes" if this is true
if not console.log, what this should be?

Comment: `if (2<3) console.log ('yes')`

Comment: http://jshint.com/ or http://jslint.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors with your code:

1. You have to remove the `,` because it is invalid syntax.
2. You need to add quotation marks around the word yes to make it a string.

You code should look like this:

```
if (2<3) console.log ('yes')
```

Then you should see 'yes' printed in your console.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this is due to syntax problems. There shouldn't be a comma, and the yes should be 'yes' or "yes".

```
if (2<3) console.log ('yes');
```

OR

```
if (2<3) console.log ("yes");
```

should work how you want it to. JavaScript does not know that you are trying to output a string. What you are doing in the code you provided is actually trying to print out a variable that is named yes. If you would like to print out a variable named yes, it would be something along the lines of

```
var yes = "yes";

if(2<3) console.log(yes);
```

Be very careful of syntax!